# How to group conditional expressions when using [[ ]] in zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to group conditional expressions in zsh.

```
if [[ ( ! chkchroot ) || ( $# -lt 1 ) ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 [command]"
    echo "       run this inside a chroot"
    return 1
fi
```

However this fails with a parsing error. Here, `chkchroot` is a shell function.

In pure POSIX, one can do this.

```
if [ \( ! chkchroot \) -o \( $# -lt 1 \) ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 [command]"
    echo "       run this inside a chroot"
    return 1
fi
```

Is there a way one can do this with the `[[ ]]` syntax in zsh?

Comment: Your POSIX is syntactically correct but semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have a tool `chkchroot` that you want to run. Your posted code is not how you run commands in an if statement.

To run `chkchroot` as a command, do not include it inside `[[ .. ]]`:

```
if ! chkchroot || [[ $# -lt 1 ]]
then
  echo "foo"
fi
```

Bash interprets your `chkchroot` as an implicit `-n chkchroot` (which is always true and **does not** run chkchroot). Zsh does not allow this, which is why it complains. It's not related to the parentheses.